# Python Merge lists together in one list without blanks

Tags: python, list, csv, merge

I have three lists and the blank spaces of one List are filled by another list. So I want to complete the first list with the other two lists.
Example:

```
L1=[1,2,None,None,5,None,7,None,None,10]
L2=[None,None,3,4,None,None,None,None,9,None]
L3=[None,None,None,None,None,6,None,8,None,None]
result_List= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

The list come from an XML Export and .append Function. So my goal is to insert all the Elements into the first column. With .append it creates many columns and .extend just writes them behind each other with the blank Elements.

Note: the values are strings with 25 digits and are mixed letters and numbers, so i cannot compare the values in the lists. They are only compareable by the position/index they stand.

Comment: No, you don't have anything like that. `[1,2,,,5,,7,,,10]` is just a syntax error. What do you **really** have?

Comment: Is this what you have `L1=[1,2,None,None,5,None,7,None,None,10]`?
What you mention _blank spaces_ does not exist in Python.

Comment: You are right, i always have a "None" between the numbers. In the csv export the "None" gets deleted, so i didn't wrote that down...

Comment: Do you know how to write a `for` loop with an index variable that runs from 0 to some number?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L1=[1,2,None,None,5,None,7,None,None,10]
>>> L2=[None,None,3,4,None,None,None,None,9,None]
>>> L3=[None,None,None,None,None,6,None,8,None,None]
>>> [a or b or c for a, b, c in zip(L1, L2, L3)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Perfect, that works great! I have another program where i have 14 lists like that and it worked without any problem! Thank you :)

Comment: If one of the elements of the list is 0 the loop will return `None` instead of 0 because `bool(0)` is `False`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to be able to handle any number of input lists:

```
L1=[1,2,None,None,5,None,7,None,None,10]
L2=[None,None,3,4,None,None,None,None,9,None]
L3=[None,None,None,None,None,6,None,8,None,None]
new_l = [next(filter(None, i)) for i in zip(L1, L2, L3)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: If one of the elements of the list is 0 this method will raise `StopIteration`. I use a lambda function to filter and it works great: `[next(filter(lambda x: x is not None, i)) for i in zip(L1, L2, L3)]`